# Ember.js each loop : compare current index data with previous index data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In ember.js each loop, How can I access the data of the previous index inside the current loop?

```
{{#each coonfigData key="name" as |band index|}}

  {{#if band.min >  band(index-1).min}} //compare current min with previous min

     <div>Something</div>

  {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

I know I can create a helper to store the previous index data inside the template scope, but is there any template only way? If not, what will be the most elegant way using a helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [ember-math-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-math-helpers) and use `sub` helper for subtract operation like
and you can install [ember-truth-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers) and use `gt` helper for greater than condition and finally [built-in](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/built-in-helpers/) `get` helper for retrieving the previous element from the list like this:

```
{{#each configData key="name" as |band index|}}

  {{#if (gt band.min (get (get configData (sub index 1)) min))}} //compare current min with previous min

     <div>Something</div>

  {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

Comment: A similar solution would be `previous` template helper provided by `ember-composable-helpers`: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#previous